How can I copy and paste an image texture to another mesh, then edit that copy and pasted one?
I have painted a texture using texture paint and put in on my model with an image texture. I have duplicated the mesh and material that I painted. I now want to copy the image texture, paste it as a new image texture, and modify that one to add some differences to the second image texture. Is this possible? I tried this and when I re-opened blender, both models had the new texture.

First Open the Image Editor:

Then go to Image> Save a Copy :

I hope that's answering your question.
